# Import (ImageMagick) does not capture overlays

Tags: gnome, imagemagick

I've been using `import` from Imagemagick to take screenshot of my second monitor every 15 seconds, and then later assembled the images using `mencoder` - thus creating a timelapse of what has been going on on my desktop during the time.  This worked great when I used Gnome 2 - but as of late, my shots has gotten several artifacts in them.  Black rectangles appearing in various places.

This does not occur with gnome-screenshot, but I need something that is powerful enough to do the equivilent to this:

```
# Capture 1920 x 1080 to file, starting at position 1680 x 0 (Monitor to the
# left is 1680x1050, monitor to the right is 1920 x 1080 - I want to capture the
# monitor to the right.)

while [ 1 ]; do
    import -window root -crop 1920x1080+1680+0 ~/img/foo-$(date +%y%m%d-%H%M%S).jpg
    sleep 15
done
```

and `gnome-screenshot` does not seem to have the options available to do this.  I have not found any way to make the artifacts in the shots of `import` go away.

Does anyone have any clever suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

I have had some pretty good luck with xwd. I screenshot the whole desktop then use imagemagick to cut out just the portion I want.

I have also been using the tool's ability to pull from specific window titles.

http://blog.tordeu.com/?p=135

Using the information on that blog post I have created the following python function which I use to take screenshots of a window with "mywindow" in the title bar.

```
def store_mywindow_screenshot():
    command = 'xdotool windowraise `xdotool search --title ".*mywindow.*"`'
    os.system(command)
    command = 'xwd -id `xdotool search --title ".*mywindow.*"` -out mywindow_screenshot.xwd'
    os.system(command)
    command = "convert mywindow_screenshot.xwd mywindow_screenshot_%s.png" % datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    os.system(command)
```

As I have been capturing a window that is a 3d opengl app, i imagine xwd would be robust enough for your application